# Perl - "if" condition is not working as expect

Tags: perl

i want to compare two strings and print "yes" if it matches. when i print string values are same. But script prints "No" matching.

Perl script:

```
foreach my $lines(@mylogFileLines)
{
    if ($lines =~ m/^*.ERROR/i)
    {

        my @errorline = split ('/',$lines);
        my @getline = split ('  ',$errorline[4]);
        my @vresp_id = $resp_id;
        @mygetline = $getline[0];
        foreach my $resp (@vresp_id)
        {

            print "$resp --- $getline[0]\n";
            if ($resp =~ $getline[0])
            {
                $remarks = "Error";
                print "yesss-\n";
            }
            else
            {
                print "no\n";
                $remarks = "-";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Command line output:

```
dom_RESP_2018-03-02T14-26-29-029+10-00.xml --- dom_RESP_2018-03-02T14-26-29-029+10-00.xml
no
testing_RESP_2018-03-02T14-26-29-029+10-00.xml --- dom_RESP_2018-03-02T14-26-29-
029+10-00.xml
```

Comment: I've cleaned up the indentation of your code. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself next time. Good indentation is one of the most useful tools for understanding code and if you're asking a group of strangers to read and understand your code, it is only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Comment: Please show us the contents of `@mylogFileLines` when this code is executed.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `eq` operator for string equality. `=~` interprets the right hand side as a regular expression, where `+` has a special meaning, so

```
'a+b' eq 'a+b'  # true
'a+b' =~ /a+b/  # false, `+` is not matched
```

To interpret `+` literally in a regex, you need to escape it:

```
'a+b' =~ /a\+b/  # true
```

You can use the [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) function to auto-escape all non-word characters.